# How to make an image completely black and white? (force pixel values to #000 or #fff)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to make an image completely black and white. By "completely" I mean the ONLY colors pixels can be are #000 or #fff.

I have about 20 `Black & White`, `Levels`, and `Brightness/Contrast` layers over an image layer, but there are STILL some pixels that aren't completely black or white :-(

How can I make an image completely black and white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

> image>adjustment>threshold

The result will be an only black and white image, play with the handlers to get to the desired image.

I personally recommend doing these on a duplication of the photo layer and not the original just invade you want to change something